# Combine str_replace with substr

Tags: php, arrays

My conjugation script combines `$stamm(2)` with all endings from the 2 dimensional array called `$array`.

part of a foreach loop

```
$array[3][0] = str_replace($stamm, $stamm2.'o</u>', $value). $red_slash.str_replace($stamm, $stamm2.'ié</u>', $value);
```

for example

```
$stamm2='begin';
$stamm3='begin2';
$array[3][0] = array ('irai','iras','ira','irons','irez','iront');
```

Now I have a case with 2 different regular verb forms with different roots (`$stamm2` and `$stamm3`) but also different endings (`$array[3][0]`).
In the second option should be everytime the first ending letter i deleted.

How is it possible to add substr function or something else what would help me for this part?

`str_replace($stamm, $stamm2.'ié</u>', $value);`

output: (without the adding the strings  o/ié to  `$stamm2`/`$stamm3`)

```
beginirai / begin2irai
beginiras / begin2iras
beginira / begin2ira
beginirons / begin2irons
beginirez / begin2irez
beginiront / begin2iront
```

desired output: (without the adding the strings  o/ié to  `$stamm2`/`$stamm3`)

```
beginirai / begin2rai
beginiras / begin2ras
beginira / begin2ra
beginirons / begin2rons
beginirez / begin2rez
beginiront / begin2ront
```

Comment: Didn't really understand, can you please provide an example of your input and desired output?

Comment: @OfirBaruch I have add my output and desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood from your `desired output`, I wrote the following code:
(Let me know if I didn't understand you well in the comments section)

```
$prefix1 = 'begin';
$prefix2 = 'begin2';

$inputArr = array('irai', 'iras', 'ira', 'irons', 'irez', 'iront');
$outputArr1 = array();
$outputArr2 = array();

foreach($inputArr as $input){
 $outputArr1[] = $prefix1 . $input; //for instance: beginirai
 $outputArr2[] = $prefix2 . substr($input, 1); //for instance: begin2rai
}
```

Comment: Well, I think this would be right, but I don't know how to change the whole system, maybe you have some free time to see the whole script and help me to improve it? In my foreach the $inputArr isn't mentioned.

Comment: I'm sorry but not really, the purpose of SO is to provide general help for common issues, your case is kind of a very specific problem. If you want to can try to generalize your problem and open a new question related to it.

Comment: @ Ofir Baruch I don't know how to use the original array for the endings, thats why I create for 2 different times (where I should only delete the first letter i) new arrays and use them like in your answer without  `substr`.